# How to read a memory address in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In ANSI C I can do this:

```
const long *address = 0x00000002;  /* Example address */
printf("0x00000002 -> %ld", *address);
```

And the console will show the content of that memory address. But that code in VC++ throws:

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'const long *'

Is there a native way to read memory addresses from VC++ or I have to call the API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "In...Standard C++ I can do this."  No you cannot.

Comment: The way you're trying to read the address is correct (correct-ish)… the primary problem is that you've selected an address you may not have permission to read. You can't just take an arbitrary memory location and start accessing it (at least not without mapping it in somehow). As to your code error, `const long *address = (const long *)0x00000002;` will let you compile (and probably crash at run time, either for trying to access memory on a protected address, or possibly for trying to access it without proper alignment).

Comment: This is done a lot on embedded systems with memory mapped IO.  It is a perfectly valid thing to do in that context because you know the physical address of the IO you want to access.  But the number of the address isn't really a pointer from the view of the compiler - just cast the physical address to the right type and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set that address, use a cast like

```
const long* address = (const long*) 0x0000002;  // C style
```

or

```
const long* address = 
   reinterpret_cast<const long*>(0x000002); // C++ style
```

BTW, on most systems 0x0000002 is not a valid address (in the usual virtual address space of applications). See wikipage on [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) & [virtual address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

Comment: Thanks. The 0x0000002 is an example address. The C Style works fine without casting, but like this won't throw a warning :-)

Answer (score 4):

You have the address expressed as an integer. You need to cast it to a pointer of the appropriate type:

```
const long *address = reinterpret_cast<const long *>(0x00000002);
```

And you need to perform that cast in standard C++. I'm not sure why you think that the cast can be omitted in standard C++.

Of course, when you run your code, you will encounter a segmentation fault.

Comment: Oh, yes, I was compiling with a C compiler (not C++). Thanks.

Comment: It's only a segmentation fault on machines with virtual memory.  On an machine with a 6502 processor the entire zero page is basically a huge set of registers and you NEED to use them to write anything relatively non-trivial.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah VC++ doesn't run on 6502